# Why I'm getting This page isn’t working currently unable to handle this request HTTP ERROR 500 in laravel dashboard?

Tags: laravel

This page isn’t working www.example.com is currently unable to handle this request
HTTP ERROR 500 in laravel site after login to dashboard. I tried with index.php and storage permission (644, 777) too but its not working till. Can anyone provide me best solution to resolve this issue. It was working well in previous server and other laravel sites migrated to same server aren't facing this issue.

Comment: Check the error logs for what's happening

Comment: Thanks doing same job for last three hours but got solution just..

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this problem by adding the code below before line 325 of /public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php file

> ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpwyt.png)